# How can I assign a new value to an object without repeating the object name (direct overwrite)?

Tags: r

I find the code for overwriting an object in R redundant and clunky. I am wondering if there is any shortcut to modify or apply an operation to an object without repeating its name. Here's an example:

if `df` is a dataframe with a column called `monkey`, I would like to, for example, calculate the log on such column and overwrite its values. I would do

```
df$monkey=log(df$monkey)
```

Is there a way to do `log(df$monkey)` and overwrite the object, like a shortend for "overwrite the object"? When you have objects with long names, like df or lists of lists, it becomes cumbersome and slow, particularly when you work directly on the console, or when quickly testing operations. So often I find myself using short object names like `t` or `a` just to avoid this long syntax.

Comment: what programming language do you use apart from R that has this "non-clunky" functionality? Btw: your view of "clunkness" is alternately known as really straightforward and easy to read and understand explicit syntax that fully describes intent and not just relying on implicit side effects. that's generally "A Very Good Thing". `log(df$monkey)` _actually modifying_ `df$monkey` sounds like a really bad idea (and I think that most folks would agree)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried to ask a technical question so it's irrelevant to get into personal views of what's practical and what is not.

Comment: It's actually a technical discussion about programming. Apologies if you're not able to see that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, something like overwrite(counter+1), could be a simple solution as an alternative to counter=counter+1.

Comment: @HermanToothrot You can write such a function using Rcpp. I wouldn't recommend it since it violates R's design principles, but it is possible and relatively easy (and not too different to what the data.table package does).

Answer (score 2):

The general answer to your question is "No, there is not."

However:

First of all, RStudio's auto-complete is a huge help with long variable names.

In base R you can use `with` and `within`, but they only save typing if you need several assignments:

```
iris <- within(iris, {
  Sepal.Length <- log(Sepal.Length)
  Sepal.Width <- log(Sepal.Width)
  })
```

My alternative of choice is the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)
iris[, Sepal.Length := log(Sepal.Length)]
```

I like the syntax (you avoid writing the data.table name multiple times) and it is also very efficient (with large data).

Another alternative is the dplyr package with its `mutate` and related functions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I always use DT but I didn't know it could overwrite columns like that. Where in the DT help file do I find such function?

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment correctly: `help(":=")` and of course the excellent data.table vignettes.

Answer (score 0):

This function will I think answer your question:

```
ovw <- function(x, f) {
  assign(x , f(eval(parse(text=x))), .GlobalEnv)
}

longnamevar <- 1
ovw("longnamevar", log)
longnamevar
[1] 0
```

In case you want to use another function than `log`, for example `x/100`, you can do:

```
ovw("longnamevar", function(x) x/100)
longnamevar
[1] 0.01
```

Also works with `function(x) x+1` and so on... Note that in the first case, `log` could be replaced by `function(x) log(x)` which is identical

Comment: That's a way to go about it. But it's somewhat specific. Sometime I just need to perform simple operations like divide by 100 or add 1.